# CSS Structure for custom theming(skinning) asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am developing a web application which will be hosted  on multiple domains with different look and feel(UI).So I am planing the structure for static content(CSS,Image,JS) so that If I want to host same application on  more than one domain I need to do less changes in CSS. so I have planed following sturucture

- Resources

  - CSS

    - rootstyle.css (here I will place positioned related styles)
  - CSS for Site1

    - CustomTheme.css
  - CSS for Site2

    - CustomTheme.css

so here I will create a separate folder for each site and will write a customtheme css for the  site.Am I doing right or there is any other better way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `App_Themes` folder for this purpose.

You can create different folder inside it. 
Example:-

1. RedTheme
2. GreenTheme
3. YellowTheme

and you can put your individual style sheet of theme file inside this.

Here is a good example
http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/dynamic-themes-123058

Comment: I don't want to use theme problem is that I have to write whole css in each and every theme as I have written in my question I will write root css which will be common for all theme( like width, height,placing etc.) and in custom theme folder I will write look and feel related( color, font face etc..)

Comment: will you specify `style` in individual page? means will you use `page_preinit` to add style sheet on individual page?

Comment: I will use master page and apply css there and based on app setting value in web config custom theme will be applied like <link src="rootstyle.css"/>  will be common and for custom theme I will you some server side code to get custom theme path like : <link src='<%=string.Format("/resources/css/{0}/custometheme",GeneralUtility.GetThemePath()) %>'/>